# nuxt js in page import page with slug

Tags: javascript, import, slug, nuxt.js

I want importing in page another page ,but route don't change

```
<script>
import Customizer from '~/pages/customizer/_id.vue';

export default Customizer;
</script>
```

working route:
`http://localhost:8080/customizer/5d981e43056d73001757d85b`
and need work an this:
`http://localhost:8080/customizer/5d981e43056d73001757d85b/5df94193f9a39100179c7210`